# Google chrome(62) Inspector Style-sheet location

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

First off, I know a question like this already exists and I have browsed through it but the answers given aren't up-to-date enough for Chrome 62.

With 62, I know you can view style-sheets by simply clicking on the stylesheet in the style-rules tab however when i add styles to elements, there is no link to a style sheet next to them.

I also know that if you go into sources and right click on a file you can see the modifications to it but the problem is, I don't know which file I am modifying.

Has Google took away the option to view changes made while using the developer?

[image: Stylesheet link missing]

Comment: Adding a style properties to an element in Chrome devtools seems to be different from adding a style properties to a css stylesheet. The first modify only the html (not the style sheet) file so only the element instead of all the element in the css. In which version where you able to see a different behaviour and you see the stylesheet associated to the element?

Comment: What Fabio is basically saying is the top one only makes changes to the style attribute(element.style in JavaScript, hence why it has element.style as the selector), you have to click the plus in the top right to add a new CSS rule to a stylesheet (called the 'inspector stylesheet' I believe?)